# R- pass argument to ggplot in function

Tags: r, function, ggplot2, arguments

I have a question about how to pass an argument to ggplot if I want to have a `1-x` x-axis. The function is being used to specify column name in my data frame.

Let's say my data frame looks like

```
x1    x2    x3   x4
0.1   0.2   0.3  0.4
0.3   0.5   0.7  0.9
0.4   0.6   0.8  0.2
```

And I have a function

```
myfunction<- function(x, y, convert = False){

if (flip) {
  ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=1-get(x), y=get(y))) + geom_line() + 
  xlab(x) + ylab(y)
    } else {
  ggplot(data = mydata, aes(x=get(x), y=get(y))) + geom_line() + 
  xlab(x) + ylab(y)
    }
}
```

It works when convert = False, but if I want to plot `myfunction(x1, x2, convert = TRUE)`, my x-lab is still `"x1"`, not `"1-x1"`. I have tried to code `xlab(1-get(x))` but it doesn't work. Anyone have an idea about how to print x-label as `"1-x1"`, where x1 is a column name in a data frame?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the function arguments, it seems like `convert` is `flip`.  Instead of using `get` to modify the 'x' argument, we can do this with `mutate` after converting the arguments to quosures

```
myfunction<- function(mydata, x, y, convert = FALSE){
    x <- enquo(x)
    y <- enquo(y)
    xnew <- quo_name(x)
if (convert) {
   mydata %>%
         mutate(!! (xnew) := 1- !!(x)) %>%
         ggplot(., aes_string(xnew, quo_name(y))) +
               geom_line() + 
               xlab(paste0("1 - ", xnew))
   
} else {

     ggplot(mydata, aes_string(xnew, quo_name(y))) +
             geom_line()

    }
    
}

myfunction(df1, x1, x2, convert = TRUE)
```

-output

[image]

```
myfunction(df1, x1, x2, convert = FALSE)
```

-output

[image]

#### data

```
df1 <- structure(list(x1 = c(0.1, 0.3, 0.4), x2 = c(0.2, 0.5, 0.6), 
x3 = c(0.3, 0.7, 0.8), x4 = c(0.4, 0.9, 0.2)), .Names = c("x1", 
"x2", "x3", "x4"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -3L
))
```

Comment: Thanks! When I try to run the code, it prompts out an error message `Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : Evaluation error: non-numeric argument to binary operator.`. Probably because my actual function is like `myfunction<- function(mydata, x = c("x1", "x2"), y = c("x2", "x3"), convert = False)`, and I call my function by `myfunction(mydata, x = "x2", y="x3")`. Do you have an idea about how to solve this problem?

Comment: @Helen I provided a reproducible example and the arguments of the function.  You can test it on that

Comment: The function works great for this example. The problem is that I have also used `y <- match.arg(y)` in my function body to prompt an error if the user specifies a y variable other than "x2" or "x3".  Is there a way to modify your solution but still takes argument like `x = c("x1", "x2"), y = c("x2", "x3")` ?

Comment: @Helen Are you passing the arguments are quoted strings or not.  In your post, the function is taking unquoted variable names.  It is not clear now from the comments.  why you pass `x` with two column names and y with same

Comment: Sorry I made a mistake when posting the question. I did take quoted variable names in my original function, but now I have changed it. Thanks! It works now.